# Found 'UR'-anomaly for variable 'city' (lines 'XX'-'YY')

Tags: java

Small question regarding how to fix a 'UR'-anomaly please.

On this very simple piece of code:

```
 private final Environment          environment;
    private final Map<String, Foo> partnerConfiguration;
    @Value("something")
    private List<String> goodCities;


    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        for (final String city : goodCities) {
            final String   nameAndCountry = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_PREFIX + city);
            final String[] nameAndCountrySplit  = Objects.requireNonNullElse(nameAndCountry, "").split(";");
            final String   name        = nameAndCountrySplit[0];
            final String   country   = nameAndCountrySplit[1];
            partnerConfiguration.put(city, new Foo(name, country));
        }
    }
```

I got flagged with 'UR'-anomaly on those lines:

```
   public void setup() {
        for (final String city : goodCities) {
            final String   nameAndCountry = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_PREFIX + city);
```

I tried using a functional version of it, refactoring by creating a sub method, changing variable names, no luck.

I know static analysis tools are just tools, but I am quite interested what would be the code level answer on how to fix this "anomaly" please.

Thank you

Comment: What is a "UR"-anomaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[7 year old bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1190/).

Your code is completely fine, it's the linter tool that misunderstands java constructs and is now throwing out irrelevant warnings.

Stop using this tool. It's unmaintained, and as a result, it just doesn't understand any java code with 'modern' features anymore, and this isn't even a modern language construct (it was when PMD was in its final days of maintenance).

There are many other java linter tools out there. Heck, most IDEs ship with a decent set already.

NB: Your question doesn't mention the word 'pmd' and isn't tagged 'pmd', so I'm guessing. You should update your question. Next time you ask on SO, please be aware that those reading your question do not have a crystal ball and have no idea what kind of setup you're running. If this warning is being printed out not by PMD but something else, this answer is probably not nearly as useful.

Comment: Upvote the answer, as I am now clear what is it about. But just asking, is there really no way to resolve the issue, even knowing the 'UR'-anomaly flag does not make sense?

Comment: There is no way, and the fact that something so simple is already causing PMD to get confused, as well as your intent to write lambda code which PMD is going to just completely skip and/or get incredibly confused about, makes it exceedingly clear that you gotta stop using PMD ASAP.